# In one column date is replaced with word [Table] when combining files via power query

Tags: powerquery

I am using power query to combine a set of xml files. There's a specific column that has a date on the original file but when data is transformed and files are combined I get [Table] written all across the column when I expect dates. Maybe the answer is simple but I cannot figure out.

[image]

I am not an advanced user of power query, this is as far as I can go - combining files.

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle the checkmark on that answer to mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand those columns

Go into home .. advanced editor ... remove the bottom row **in xxx**, add a comma to the end of the new bottom row then copy and paste this code below that:

```
ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(#"UseYourPriorStepNameHere"[CORTEXDATE], each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
ColumnsToExpand2 = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(#"UseYourPriorStepNameHere"[CRDACPTID], each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
#"Expand" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"UseYourPriorStepNameHere", "CORTEXDATE", ColumnsToExpand, ColumnsToExpand),
#"Expand2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expand", "CRDACPTID", ColumnsToExpand2, ColumnsToExpand2)
in #"Expand2"
```

Then 3 times, replace where it says #"UseYourPriorStepNameHere" with whatever actually was the prior step name in your code (the part before the equals sign after you removed the in xxx line)

[image]